# I cant get my player to Jump, even thought the code is very similar to a working example

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've been learning how to use pygame and came across a tutorial for making your character jump. The code isn't exactly the same, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

I'm wondering why he would make the jump count `False` initially if he was going to ask:

```
if not (p1jump):
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        p1jump = True
```

This is confusing to me because `p1jump` is false initially. So you're basically asking: if p1jump is true, and SPACE is pressed, then set p1jump to true.

Here's the whole class just in case:

```
class Player1():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = 25
        self.width = 25
        self.speed = 5
    def draw(self,r,g,b):
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(r,g,b),(self.x,self.y, self.width ,self.height))
    def movement(self):
        p1jump = False
        jumpcount = False
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a] and self.x > self.speed:
            self.x -= self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_d] and self.x < (w - self.width):
            self.x += self.speed

        if not(p1jump):
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                p1jump = True
        else:
            if jumpcount >= -10:
                self.y -= (jumpcount **2) *0.5
                jumpcount = 1

            else:
                p1jump = False
                jumpcount = 10
```

Also, if you guys have any better ways to code a jump please let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet is correct. However, in the method `movement` you're setting `p1jump` to `False` every time it's called. I'm guessing you want it to keep being `True` until the player lands. So make that variable an attribute instead.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        # ... stuff
        self.jump = False

    def movement(self):
        # ... stuff

        if not self.jump and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.jump = True
        else:
            if jumpcount >= -10:
                self.y -= (jumpcount **2) *0.5
                jumpcount = 1
            else:
                self.jump = False
                jumpcount = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

> So you're basically asking: if p1jump is true, and SPACE is pressed,
>   then set p1jump to true.

Not exactly, `not (p1jump):` is `True` if p1jump is `False`. `not` is an inverse operator in Python.

`if not (p1jump)` could be rewritten as `if p1jump == False` if that's clearer to you.

I hope that helps.